# Power loss Vs. Distance

Tags: netlogo

I am doing a simple radio propagation model in netlogo where i have to generate a plot of power loss Vs. Distance.Is there a way to plot one quantity vs other instead of one vs ticks. Any advice on procedures is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: please add information about where you want to plot your data. Matlab, Excel, GnuPlot,.....? Also edit your tags so they reflect this.

Comment: Oh I am terribly sorry, I thought i was writing in Netlogo topics forum.Actually, I was doing this in Netlogo simulation Environment. For my model, the power is constant whereas the distance of the nodes varies.

Answer (score 2):

The [`plotxy`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plotxy) primitive lets you do that.

I don't know how your power loss and distance data is stored, but let's build a quick example using turtles `xcor` and `ycor` as data. You should be able to adapt it easily.

Here is the very basic model:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 100 patches [ sprout 1 ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [ fd 1 ]
  tick
end
```

Now you can create a plot. Put [`clear-plot`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#clear-plot) in the plot update commands and `ask turtles [ plotxy xcor ycor ]` in the pen updates commands:

[image]

Also make sure that your pen is set to "point mode" in the advanced pen options, or you'll get a jumble of lines:

[image]

(Access the pen options by clicking on the pen icon next to the pen definition in the plot dialog.)

Comment: Great! Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way. Since you're new here, you may want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).